# Get the last modified date of a file in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

I'm trying to display the last modified date if a `FileField` item. I've managed to get the size of the file by:

```cs
Sitecore.Data.Fields.FileField ff = document.File;
Item i = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(document.File.MediaID));
MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem(i);
mediaItem.Size;
```

I can't seem to find a way to get a file's last modified date. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have last modified date on Update field. This is a standard field in Sitecore.

```
  var lastModifiedDate= mediaItem.InnerItem.Statistics.Updated;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `InnerItem` which will return the Sitecore `Item` object and get `Updated` property from the statistics like that:

```cs
DateTime lastModified = mediaItem.InnerItem.Statistics.Updated;
```

Comment: Both answered are ok, Marek was 20 seconds faster :D

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can get that by using one of these:

1. i.Statistics.Updated - returns DateTime
2. i[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Updated] - returns String, convert it to DateTime
3. DateField date = i.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Updated];